# Analysis and sets. Express #Y in terms of #X.

Tags: analysis

So the assignemnt question reads

"Let X be a finite set and
Y := {(A, B, C) A, B, C ⊂ X, X = A ∪ B ∪ C, A ∩ B = A ∩ C = B ∩ C = ∅}
Express #Y in terms of #X. Counting the set Y in two different ways gives formula involving powers and binomial coefficients. Derive this."

My thoughts are that Y is counting partitions into 3 distinguished disjoint sets. One way to think about it, each element of X can be independently put in one of A,B,C. Another way, you could count over all i+j+k=|X|, 0<=i,j,k, the ways to select A,B,C using binomial coefficient. Those may be what the two ways the question means. The trouble I'm having is how to write this out in an accurate manner. Any help is much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $|X|=n$. Since it seems you already have an idea, I will just write out what you said:

**Counting method 1**

Each element of $X$ can be put into one of the sets $A,B,C$, so given that we have $|X|=n$, possible number of ways to do this is just $3^n$. Hence

$$
|Y|=3^{|X|}
$$

Now your second argument is not correct (as far as I correctly understand what you meant): I think what you meant was to find out number of different triplets $(i,j,k)$ where $i,j,k$ are non-negative integers representing number of elements in $A,B,C$. Then you permute $A,B,C$ (6 ways) to get $|Y|$, so $|Y|=6l$ where $l$ is number of different triplets.

But this seems to not work after I tried it, instead I believe the following is what is required:

**Counting method 2**

From slightly different point of view: we can first choose $i$ elements from the set $X$ and put them into $A$, then choose $j$ from remaining elements in $X$ and put them into $B$, then the rest goes to $C$. That is, we have

$$
|Y|=\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} {n \choose i} {n-i \choose j}
=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} {n-i \choose j}=\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{n-i}{n \choose i} 
$$

**Conclusion**

We have

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{n-i}{n \choose i} = 3^n
$$

---

After I thought about it a bit, above can more easily be deduced from binomial theorem only:
$$
(2+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{n-i} {n \choose i}
$$

so I'm not sure if the problem was looking for this kind of formula...